# How to run Shiny custom input control example on my desktop?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to use this shiny control:

[Shiny "custom input control" example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/custom-input-control.html)

in my own shiny app.

But when I copy-paste all codes and folders from the github repository ("Get code" link in the Shiny example page above)
into my own folder and run the server app from there with Rstudio,
the buttons do not work and the list stay empty (NULL) while Shiny gallery shows something different and usable with the bottom text field displaying the content of each list and selecting and clicking on the buttons updates the lists and the text field.

[image: See image here]

What shall I do to use this code? Usually other codes for widgets in Shiny Gallery are very easy to use directly, just copy-paste and it works well.

I failed to understand what is told in the "Packaging note" in the README.md file on github:

> This example is set up for easy reading of the code and easy running via shiny::runGitHub().
>
> If instead we wanted to make this line chart component easily distributable to other Shiny users, we would set it up as a package. chooser.R would go into the R subdirectory. The contents of www would be moved to inst, and chooserInput would call shiny::addResourcePath to make them available at a URL prefix like "chooser". See shiny-incubator for one example.

I am not a javascript expert, the "shiny-incubator" example mentionned is of no help to me, and I cannot setup a client-server easily on my machine, usually with Shiny I don't need to.

What shall I do?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the `www` directory? Looks like you may have left out the script in there.

Comment: @greg L, Not sure I understand your point, I copy-pasted everything on my local folder, preserving the structure, so I do have a local directory with the R functions and a subdirectory called www containing the javascript code as on github. I tried to rename this folder "inst", and also tried to put the javascript code in the upper folder with ui.r, chooser.r and server.r, but get the same non-working result. In chooser.r there is a call to chooser-binding.js on line 16: "tags$script(src="chooser-binding.js")" but I am not sure why it fails in my case.